# How to set bitrate mode CBR to podcast XML

Tags: xml, itunes, podcast

I created a podcast xml for iTunes. Following is my xml data.

```
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>Podcast</title>
    <link>https://www.example.com/</link>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <copyright>Copyright example.com</copyright>
    <itunes:subtitle>Podcast</itunes:subtitle>
    <itunes:author>Name</itunes:author>
    <itunes:summary>Summary</itunes:summary>
    <description>Description</description>
    <itunes:owner>
        <itunes:name>Name</itunes:name>
        <itunes:email>me@example.com</itunes:email>
    </itunes:owner>
    <itunes:explicit>clean</itunes:explicit>
    <itunes:image href="https://example.com/iamge.png"/>
    <itunes:category text="Business"/>
    <itunes:category text="Technology"/>
    <itunes:category text="Music"/>
    <itunes:category text="News"/>
    <item>
         <title>Title</title>
         <itunes:author>Me</itunes:author>
         <itunes:subtitle>Subtitle</itunes:subtitle>
         <itunes:summary>Long description....</itunes:summary>
         <itunes:image href="https://example.com/image2.jpg"/>
         <enclosure url="https://example.com/media.m4a" length="22:24" type="audio/x-m4a"/>
         <link>https://www.example.com/podcast/title</link>
         <pubDate>Fri, 11 Dec 2015 4:43:43 GMT</pubDate>
         <category>Tech News</category>
         <itunes:duration>22:24</itunes:duration>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I'm validating my podcast from this [tool](https://castfeedvalidator.com/)

I'm getting warning as **Your bitrate mode is not set to CBR. This is the optimal setting for podcast audio.**

How to set bitrate mode. I'm using LAMP.

Please suggest.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to modify the settings in whatever tool you are using to produce the audio file for your podcast episodes.

CBR refers to Constant Bit Rate [initial info here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_bitrate)

The alternative method is Variable Bit Rate (VBR)

CBR is the recommended encoding method when creating a voice recording.

There are several reasons/opinions why CBR is preferred to VBR for a podcast episode.

To answer your question, the tool you are using to validate you feed has (probably) detected that your audio files are not encoded using CBR. It is recommending that you fix this.

You will need to go back to the source and read the documentation for the tool you are using to generate your audio files.